# Can't click on ActiveX control in Excel 2010 Standard

Tags: microsoft-excel, microsoft-excel-2010, vba, macros

I have a .xlsm file that has ActiveX control button with a module macro assigned to it. Problem is I can't click the ActiveX button from my Excel 2010 Standard. I tried to repair and reinstall Excel but that did not fix it. Tried adding a new ActiveX control to the worksheet but got "Cannot insert object" message. Any idea what's is going on?

**UPDATE:**
I checked as many of the security settings as I could based off Google searches, but that didn't seem to work. The icon of the excel file does have a ! sign on orange background though.

**SOLUTION:**
Uninstallting latest Microsoft Office updates solved the issue. I was uninstallting Office updates 1 by 1 until I uninstalled a big one - **Service Pack 2 for Office**. After a required restart the ActiveX button started to work. Thank you, **ajs**.

Comment: Probably a security issue. Do you allow Active X controls to be run (even if you did, best to check you still allow it). Also see http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16893446/cannot-insert-object-error-when-adding-activex-control-like-microsoft-datagrid

Comment: Please [edit your post and explain this](http://superuser.com/posts/851823/edit), it will save others from spending time when they don't need too........

Answer (score -1, accepted):

The latest Windows update killed it.  Back out the ones involving Excel and VBA and it will run again.

Comment: I'll give it a go.

Answer (score 2):

The offending update is [KB2553154](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/2553154).

The KB article lists known issues with this Security Update including the **Cannot Insert Object** error message when attempting to interact with a Forms ActiveX control in an Office document. A resolution for the issue is described in [KB3025036](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/3025036).

The resolution is to delete cached versions of the control type libraries, which means delete all files named MSForms.exd from the %TEMP% folder and all subfolders.

Comment: Thank for this, was banging my head against a wall trying to figure it out. I delete the .exd files C:\Users\[user.name]\AppData\Local\Temp\Excel8.0\MSForms.exd
C:\Users\[user.name]\AppData\Local\Temp\VBE\MSForms.exd and started Excel again and it was fine. Thanks Microsoft for another great patch!